# How to create an if statement program to calculate a tip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, if-statement, error-handling

I'm trying to write a program for my homework:

Write a program to determine how much to tip the server in a restaurant. The tip should be 15% of the check, with a minimum of $2.

The hint said to use an if statement, but i keep running into a alot of errors.

I don't know how else to write it, I've been trying to figure it out for a couple of hours now and haven't found proper answers online...

```
Check = 59
Tip = (Check)*(0.15)

if Tip > 2: 
    print(Tip)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear whether only checks larger than $2 get tips, or whether tips must be at least $2.

I'm guessing the former, because you can do that with an if statement:

```
check = 59
if check > 2:
    tip = 0.15*check
```

Or more compactly, like this:

```
tip = check*0.15 if check > 2 else 0
```

Whereas if the intent is that the tip must be at least $2, an if statement isn't really necessary:

```
check = 59
tip = max(2, 0.15*check)
```

But if you HAD to use an if statement (though `max` is more elegant), you could do it like this:

```
check = 59
tip = 0.15*check
if tip <= 2:
    tip = 2
```

But this is quite inelegant.

Comment: Tips must be at least $2 or 15% of the check amount if higher.

Comment: OK, if that's the interpretation, you should use the very last version above - but honestly that's quite inelegant, and "max" - the third version above - would be a nicer way.

Comment: Do I end the code with print(tip)? I dont know how to fix the float object not callable error when I try to print it

Comment: You can print if you want - If you're getting an error, please paste the entire code you're running into your question above, and paste the entire traceback you're getting when you run it - also into your question.

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)



Input In [286], in <cell line: 5>()

      3 if tip <= 2:
      4     tip = 2
----> 5 print(tip)

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Comment: OK. the issue was with the Jupyter notebook. I had to restart the kernel to make it work, thank you, your code worked best out of all answers.

Answer (score 0):

It means you first use `if` statement to see if the check is more than 2 before you do the math

```py
check = 59
if check > 2:
    tip = check * 0.15
    print(tip)
```

Output:

```
8.85
```

Comment: I get the float type error with this

Input In [273], in <cell line: 3>()
      3 if check > 2:
      4     tip = (check)*(0.15)
----> 5     print(tip)

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Comment: the number 2 is for the tip amount, so at least $2  tip or 15% of the check amount.

Comment: @Jamiu Shaibu's code runs without errors for me.

Comment: I guess he is doing something wrong. I just formatted the float, so he can try to see if that works for him.

Comment: could it be related to the jupyter notebook? i keep getting the "float" object not callable

Answer (score 0):

First initialise your variable `tip = 2` then if the tip percentage of 15% is higher apply the tip percentage to your variable `tip`:

```
check = 30

tip = 2
tip_perc = check * 0.15

if tip_perc > 2:
    tip = tip_perc

print(tip)
```

Comment: I get the usual float error on the print line at the end. ----> 9 print(tip)

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Comment: I'm afraid this is a problem from your side, not on the code

Comment: Do you know if using Jupyter notebook would cause this? It's what the instructor wants us to use for the homework.